# Opening same file names in multiple directories using Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, file, directory, nokogiri

Looking to do the following using Ruby:

- Directory A and Directory B will have same number of XML files and also same filenames.

**Step 1:**
* Go into directory A (directory A has X number of XML files)
* Inside directory A, take the first XML file and save the file name and also open the file

**Step 2:**
* Go into directory B (directory B will have same number of XML files with the same filenames as directory A)
* Inside directory B, open the same XML filename that was saved and opened in directory A.

**Step 3: (I've already completed this part) ** 
*** Compare the two files (I've already completed this part)**

**Step 4:**
* Repeat this for ALL XML files in both directories.

---

I've tried a few things, but for some reason the loop is happening for each file and not once, also the second loop for Dir B is not executing:

```
id_dir = "#{Dir.pwd}"+"/id_responses"
ht_dir = "#{Dir.pwd}"+"/ht_responses"

Dir.foreach(id_dir) do |id_file|
  next if id_file == '.' or id_file == '..'
  id_file = File.open("#{id_dir}/#{id_file}", 'r')
  doc1 = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse(File.open(id_file))

  Dir["#{Dir.pwd}"+"/ht_responses/#{id_file}"].each do |ht_file|
    next if id_file == '.' or id_file == '..'
    doc2 = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse(File.open(ht_file))
  end
end
```

Comment: How to best achieve the scenario above? I'v tried a few things, but for some reason the loop is happening for each file and not once, also the second loop for Dir B is not executing:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to loop through the other dir, just see if a file with the same name exists there.

```
id_dir = "#{Dir.pwd}"+"/id_responses"
ht_dir = "#{Dir.pwd}"+"/ht_responses"

Dir.foreach(id_dir) do |id_file|
  next if id_file == '.' or id_file == '..'

  id_file_path = File.join(id_dir, id_file)
  ht_file_path = File.join(ht_dir, id_file)

  next unless File.exist?(ht_file_path)

  doc1 = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse(File.open(id_file_path, 'r'))
  doc2 = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse(File.open(ht_file_path, 'r'))
end
```

Comment: I guess I won't be sure the same file is there, thus I wanted to search in the second directory for the same file name

Comment: Then you can use `File.exist?`, a lot more efficient than going through the whole directory and checking each file there if they have the same name. I added the check to the answer.

Comment: Thank you Kimmo for your help!

Comment: Kimmo, so need to make a change to the script, we have to check if there are any sub dirs in id_dir and ht_dir as part of the check.

I did this: